# CoreData update relationship method

Tags: swift, core-data, keypaths

I have two entities - `Quote` and `Customer` (one customer can have many quotes)

Say I have a managed object called `quote` but I want to update the customer address. Is there a keypath that gets me to the customer address? As in:

```
quote!.setValue(address, forKeyPath: “some_amazing_keypath")
```

Comment: What is the name of the relationship from Quote to Customer?

Comment: The name of the one to one relationship from Quote to Customer is customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Customer entity has an attribute “address” which holds the address, the keypath should just be “customer.address”:

```
quote!.setValue(address, forKeyPath: “customer.address")
```

But life would be much easier if you specify a subclass for the entity: you can then just use:

```
quote!.customer.address = address
```

Comment: Turned out the issue was with my managed context and not the keypath. I got so hung up on the error message that I ignored the error itself. Thanks!